# Configuring a Model class to make Object to Xml coversion produces details of Foreign key

Tags: java, javascript, xml, json, jaxb

I've two classes names Employer and Employee.

Employer.Java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Employer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "employer")
public class Employer implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", length = 10)
    private int id;

    @XmlElement(name = "companyName")
    @Column(name = "name", length = 50)
    private String companyName;

    // Getter and setter methods
}
```

Employee.Java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", length=10)
    private int id;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    @Column(name = "name", length=50)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "email")
    @Column(name = "email", length=50)
    private String email;

    // What should I put here If I want the details of Employer class also to be converted into xml data while Object to XML conversion using JAXB
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST},fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="employer_id")
    private Employer employer;

    // Getter and setter methods
}
```

Normally I would do it by fetching the list of data, then converting it into Json, then I parse the JSon back in javascript and using _.each I'll do my appropriate needs. In that if I want get the name of employer, I'll simple call it as `row.employer.name` (Underscore JS) to use the name. But Since it's a raw xml data here, I dont have any clue on what to do. If I can learn on how to produce nested objects data in xml, then I can proceed on, otherwise I've to do it manually by creating Object to xml manually.